# Bootstrap - Display Image in Top Bar

Tags: html, css, image

I've searched the forums, but couldn't find the exact problem.

I'm using bootstrap on a template, and I'm trying to add an image in the top bar ('topbar' - not the navigational bar).

For some reason, the image is never shown.

Here's the code (all the rest besides the image works fine):

```
<section id="topbar">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 topbar-base no-padding">
            <!--Top Bar Block-->
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 topbar-block left text-left">
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Mon - Sat: 09.00 - 19.00</li>
                    <li>Company inc.</li>
                    <li>**<img src="flag.png" alt="" height="27px" />**</li>
                    <li><a href="tel:+1 929 425 3919"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+1 929 425 3919</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="mailto:info@company.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>info@company.com</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Top Bar block-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 topbar-block text-right">
                <ul class="social">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance. I've tried a lot of things, but can't seem to get it to work.

Much appreciated,
Lance

Comment: Uh...which image are you talking about? The flag image? Or are you trying to add a background image to the element?

Comment: Indeed, the flag image.

Comment: Everything with the code is fine... i tested on my server with my own image and it works, check the directory of the image as Matmik says, maybe the extension of the file is different, are you sure is .PNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The img tag inside "topbar-block" is referencing an image "flag.png" in the same directory as your .html file is. So make sure the image is in the same folder. The code seems correct otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, that was it, how silly! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the value of the height attribute of your image is `27px`. It should be just `27`.

From the [html5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-dim-width):

> The attributes, if specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers.

By the way, this should preferably stored in a css file.

There is also other errors, like the href attribute `href="tel:+1 929 425 3919"` which is not valid. Use an [html validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to get rid of those errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there's absolutely no change. The image just doesn't appear.

Comment: Is there a valid `flag.png` image file in the same location of your html file? What the console log says?